# Blender Sapling Add-on Leaves not Showing up

Tags: add-on, sapling-addon

I am using the blender sapling add-on to try create a realistic tree. I checked the 'show leaves' box and made the leaf shape rectangular.

It looks like this.

[image]
[image: blender screen]

Then with the box checked.

[image]
[image: more blender yay]

Will it work even though nothing shows up and if not, what can I do to make the leaves appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaf scale is too small, I increased it. I now see the leaves.